# Javascript for loop with short way of checking

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to quickly check in the for loop if a user exists, if it exists then come out of the loop. I'm getting a syntax error.

I know I can use `if (condition)` etc... but I'm trying to do it a smart way. Can anyone correct it?

```
for (var isExist = false, i = 0; i < that.users.length; i++) {
    var parti = that.users[i];
    parti.id === newParti.id && (isExist = true, break);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing *smart* about code that's difficult to read or understand.

Comment: "to do it smart way" --- if "smart" here means "to implement unmaintainable spaghetti", then your solution is smart indeed.

Comment: You're trying to be "clever"... just don't

Comment: @zerkms just don't want to do boring traditional style, it wouldnt be spaghetti code anyway.

Comment: @user1595858 "it wouldnt be spaghetti code anyway" it already is. "just don't want to do boring traditional style" --- then do whatever you want and pray for next developer to not know where you live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For trying to get rid of the complexity, you can use the `for` loop to check the condition for you, instead of breaking manually.

```
var isExist = false;
for (var i = 0; !isExist && i < that.users.length; i++)
    isExist = (that.users[i].id === newParti.id);
```

Comment: Seems like it will still in the loop even after condition met based on your code

Comment: No, once we are sure a user exists, the first part of the condition: `!isExist` breaks the loop.

Comment: I just have one change var isExist = false, i =0  in for condition.

Comment: Currently that would be fine, but if the code was updated to ES6 and `var` was changed to `let`, the result of the code would be entirely different.  Using proper scoping, even when hoisting makes it unnecessary, is always a plus in my book.

Answer (score 2):

```
var isExist = that.users.some(function(i) {
    return i.id === newParti.id;
});
```

People often forget about [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) while it's extremely useful for cases like this.

And es2015 is even nicer

```
const isExist = that.users.some(i => i.id === newParti.id);
```

Comment: this was going to be my next response to a *smart* way to check users exists

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
for (var isExist = false, i = 0; i < that.users.length; i++) {
  var parti = that.users[i];
  if (parti.id === newParti.id) {
    isExist = true;
    break;
  }
}
```